# C, couldn't create a file/write information to a file

Tags: c, file, pointers, memory

I'm making a program that should reverse **.wav** audiofile, so I did it, but it doesn't seem to create any `output.wav` no matter what.

I think problem is where i try to write info to a file, maybe I messed up with memory again.

[image: directory screenshot]

**code:**

**WavHeader.h:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint8_t   BYTE;
typedef uint16_t  WORD;
typedef uint32_t  DWORD;
typedef struct
{
    BYTE   chunkID[4];
    DWORD  chunkSize;
    BYTE   format[4];
    BYTE   subchunk1ID[4];
    DWORD  subchunk1Size;
    WORD   audioFormat;
    WORD   numChannels;
    DWORD  sampleRate;
    DWORD  byteRate;
    WORD   blockAlign;
    WORD   bitsPerSample;
    BYTE   subchunk2ID[4];
    DWORD  subchunk2Size;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
WAVHEADER;
```

**reverse.c:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "wav.h"

// Number of bytes in .wav header
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./reverse input.wav output.wav\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Open input file for reading
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read header
    WAVHEADER header;
    fread(&header, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    int result = check_format(header);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        return 0; // format is okay
    }
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("File is unsupported format, ensure it extension is a .WAV\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        fclose(input);
        printf("Could not create file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Write header to file
    fwrite(&header, 1, HEADER_SIZE, output);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    int block =  get_block_size(header);


    // Write reversed audio to file

    int16_t *buffer = malloc(block); // Allocate memory for the audio buffer
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
        fclose(input);
        fclose(output);
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(input, HEADER_SIZE, SEEK_SET);

    // Calculate the number of audio blocks in the file
    long numBlocks = (header.subchunk2Size) / block;

    // Read audio blocks from input, reverse, and write to output
    for (long i = 0; i < numBlocks; i++)
    {
        fseek(input, -(i + 1) * block, SEEK_END);
        fread(buffer, block, 1, input);
        fwrite(buffer, block, 1, output);
    }

    // clean up
    free(buffer);
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}

int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    if (header.format[0] == 'W' && header.format[1] == 'A' && header.format[2] == 'V' && header.format[3] == 'E')
    {
        return 0; // if format is correct
    }
    else
    return 1; // if format is not .WAV
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    int blockSize = header.numChannels * (header.bitsPerSample / 8);
    return blockSize;
}
```

I've tried the `errno` and little debug, nothing helped. Was expecting to see `"Couldn't create file"`, but didn't, so I think problem is in writing info to a file.

Comment: `long numBlocks = (header.subchunk2Size) / block;` ??? I don't know the file format so I am wondering why you use `subchunk2Size` in this calculation... Further, you're playing fast and loose with `signed` & `unsigned` variables that should likely all be `unsigned`...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but apropos of everything.  `printf(...); exit(1);` is *always wrong*.  If you are going to exit non-zero, you should print an error message: `fprintf(stderr, ...); exit(1);`. A usage statement is  not an error message.  If you wish to respond by printing a usage statement, you ought to write `printf(...); exit(0);`  If you consider the invalid call an error rather than a request for a usage statement, you ought to write an error message and exit non-zero.  You should never print both an error message and a usage statement.

Comment: `return 0; // format is okay` - here the program terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can never reach the part where it opens the output file, because of the following:

```
    if (result == 0)
    {
        return 0; // format is okay
    }
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("File is unsupported format, ensure it extension is a .WAV\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

If `result` is `0`, it should proceed, but instead it immediately returns `0`, exiting the function.

Just delete the first `if` statement, leaving only the error check, so it looks like:

```
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("File is unsupported format, ensure it extension is a .WAV\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

That way, when `result` is `0`, it will continue on to the rest of the code.